# different results using msbuild project.sln build vs vs2008 IDE build

Tags: msbuild

I'll try and make this simple. I have a solution file Nexus.sln that contains 3 projects. Dsl, DslPackage and NexusSetup. NexusSetup depends on Dsl and DslPackage. The dependencies are setup in the IDE under Project Build Order, they are listed as Dsl, DslPackage, and NexusSetup. in the Dependencies section NexsusSetup dependes on Dsl and DslPackage. From the IDE all is happy everything builds in the proper order and succeds.

from the command line running

> msbuild Nexus.sln

the project Dslpackage never builds.

**Here is the nexus.sln file**

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00

## Visual Studio 2008

Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Dsl", "Dsl\Dsl.csproj", "{BF42BD0F-8483-443E-8F1F-1A0599642B57}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "DslPackage", "DslPackage\DslPackage.csproj", "{39171FE5-51EE-4CC4-BBEF-59D2F52C1532}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "NexusSetup", "NexusSetup\NexusSetup.csproj", "{C65D94D7-81FC-4DBE-9CB3-79384113C0DA}"
EndProject
Global
 GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
  SccNumberOfProjects = 4
  SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
  SccTeamFoundationServer = http://srvdeveltfs01.local:8080/
  SccLocalPath0 = .
  SccProjectUniqueName1 = Dsl\Dsl.csproj
  SccProjectName1 = Dsl
  SccLocalPath1 = Dsl
  SccProjectUniqueName2 = DslPackage\DslPackage.csproj
  SccProjectName2 = DslPackage
  SccLocalPath2 = DslPackage
  SccProjectUniqueName3 = NexusSetup\NexusSetup.csproj
  SccProjectName3 = NexusSetup
  SccLocalPath3 = NexusSetup
 EndGlobalSection
 GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
  Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
  Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
 EndGlobalSection
 GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
  {BF42BD0F-8483-443E-8F1F-1A0599642B57}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
  {BF42BD0F-8483-443E-8F1F-1A0599642B57}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
  {BF42BD0F-8483-443E-8F1F-1A0599642B57}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
  {BF42BD0F-8483-443E-8F1F-1A0599642B57}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
  {39171FE5-51EE-4CC4-BBEF-59D2F52C1532}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
  {39171FE5-51EE-4CC4-BBEF-59D2F52C1532}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
  {39171FE5-51EE-4CC4-BBEF-59D2F52C1532}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
  {39171FE5-51EE-4CC4-BBEF-59D2F52C1532}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
  {C65D94D7-81FC-4DBE-9CB3-79384113C0DA}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
  {C65D94D7-81FC-4DBE-9CB3-79384113C0DA}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
  {C65D94D7-81FC-4DBE-9CB3-79384113C0DA}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
 EndGlobalSection
 GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
  HideSolutionNode = FALSE
 EndGlobalSection
 GlobalSection(TextTemplating) = postSolution
  TextTemplating = 1
 EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal

Here is the build log

Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.4918
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.4918]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 7/29/2009 1:53:33 PM.
Project "c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\Nexus.sln" on node 0 (default targets).
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\Nexus.sln" (1) is building "c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\Dsl\Dsl.csproj" (2) on node 0 (default targets).
  No resources are out of date with respect to their source files. Skipping resource generation.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
DSLToolsCreateProjectItemTemplates:
Skipping target "DSLToolsCreateProjectItemTemplates" because it has no outputs.
_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory:
Skipping target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CopyAppConfigFile:
Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Dsl -> c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\Dsl\bin\Debug\FA.Nexus.Dsl.dll
Done Building Project "c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\Dsl\Dsl.csproj" (default targets).
Project "c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\Nexus.sln" (1) is building "c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\NexusSetup.csproj" (3) on node 0 (default targets).
Skipping target "CopySetupFiles" because it has no outputs.
c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\Files.wxs(35): error LGHT0100: File of type 'File' with name '..\DslPackage\bin\Release\FA.Nexus.DslPackage.dll' could not be found.
c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\Files.wxs(46): error LGHT0100: File of type 'File' with name '..\Dsl\bin\Release\FA.Nexus.Dsl.dll' could not be found.
c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\Files.wxs(59): error LGHT0100: File of type 'File' with name 'SourceDir..\DslPackage\bin\Release\FA.Nexus.DslPackage.dll' could not be found.
c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\Files.wxs(62): error LGHT0100: File of type 'File' with name '..\Dsl\bin\Release\FA.Nexus.Dsl.dll' could not be found.
c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\Files.wxs(81): error LGHT0100: File of type 'File' with name '..\Dsl\bin\Release\GeneratedCode\ClassDiagramsSchema.xsd' could not be found.
Done Building Project "c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\NexusSetup.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\Nexus.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\Nexus.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\NexusSetup.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
(Link target) -> 
  c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\Files.wxs(35): error LGHT0100: File of type 'File' with name '..\DslPackage\bin\Release\FA.Nexus.DslPackage.dll' could not be found.
  c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\Files.wxs(46): error LGHT0100: File of type 'File' with name '..\Dsl\bin\Release\FA.Nexus.Dsl.dll' could not be found.
  c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\Files.wxs(59): error LGHT0100: File of type 'File' with name 'SourceDir..\DslPackage\bin\Release\FA.Nexus.DslPackage.dll' could not be found.
  c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\Files.wxs(62): error LGHT0100: File of type 'File' with name '..\Dsl\bin\Release\FA.Nexus.Dsl.dll' could not be found.
  c:\Source\AASDK\Common\Nexus\NexusSetup\Files.wxs(81): error LGHT0100: File of type 'File' with name '..\Dsl\bin\Release\GeneratedCode\ClassDiagramsSchema.xsd' could not be found.

```
0 Warning(s)
5 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.23

Comment: Are you building it in Debug or Release mode when calling MSBuild?

Comment: Also, just to make sure are the projects configured to be build for whatever mode you are making use of? Build -> Configuration Manager.

Comment: The projects are configured for Debug/AnyCPU  & Release/AnyCPU.